# Huge delay when playing a sound clip in Java

Tags: java, audio, clip

In my simple java app I play different sounds for different events.
I'm using Java clip interface with code very similar to 
Usually the sounds play instantaneously but after a few days or hours I start to get a delay in playing the sound. I have a play() method that does the following:

```
public void play(){
    System.out.println(new Date()+" rewinding file");
    clip.setFramePosition(0);  // Must always rewind!
    System.out.println(new Date()+" Playing Sound File");
    clip.start();
    System.out.println(new Date()+" Sound file stopping or stopped? Not sure");
}
```

When the sound plays with no delay I see the following in my log file:

```
Thu Nov 26 17:17:46 SAST 2015 rewinding file
Thu Nov 26 17:17:46 SAST 2015 Playing Sound File //zero delay!!!
```

But every now and then, for no apparent reason I get the following:

```
Sun Nov 29 06:40:29 SAST 2015 rewinding file
Sun Nov 29 06:48:13 SAST 2015 Playing Sound File //8 minute delay!!!
```

The delay is huge and appears to be random, the sound clips are 1 second long at most (a simple beep sound).

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT 04/12/2015**

As @Rafael Osipov suggested I've attached a profiler to the app, and it's been running for around 18 hours. I don't see anything jumping out at me so I i'm posting the timeline when the delay occurs in hopes that someone might notice something? On a side note, if there is anything else I should be watching / profiling to try source the issue please let me know.

[image: Application Profiler]

**EDIT 07/12/2015**

Hey Everyone, I've been profiling the methods and rather than Telemetry and I think it may be showing something more obvious, please have a look at the below image and notice how *com.sun.media.sound.directaudiodevice.nwrite* Self-time (CPU) and Total Time (CPU) is the highest of all the Methods.
[image: Methods Profiler]
Since my problem is related to sound, do you think this could be the cause of my issues?

Thanks!

Comment: I would employ a profiler to collect the CPU and Memory data upon running your player application. And then analyze, what is going on. Maybe there's a GC running, or something is working in another thread etc etc.

Comment: Thanks @RafaelOsipov have you used one that you can suggest?

Comment: Yes, sure. [Netbeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/) has a decent profiler. Check this link: https://profiler.netbeans.org/